# PHP MYSQL query when I search for an item with any spaces in the name it doesnt find any results

Tags: php, mysql, search, spaces

I am building an inventory system for work, I have a search system to search the database already. But when I search for an item with any spaces in the name it doesnt find any results. Here is my script, any help would be appreciated.

```
    <?php
    // we connect to our Database
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("inventory") or die(mysql_error());

    $find = $_POST['find'];

    echo "<h2>Search Results:</h2><p>";
    //If they did not enter a search term we give them an error
    if ($find == "")
    {
    echo "<p>You forgot to enter a search term!";
    exit;
    }

    // We perform a bit of filtering
    $find = strtoupper($find);
    $find = strip_tags($find);
    $find = trim ($find);

    //Now we search for our search term, in the field the user specified
    $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM parts WHERE vendor LIKE'%$find%' OR category
    LIKE'%$find%' OR prtid LIKE'%$find%' OR description LIKE '%$find%'");
    if (!$data) { // add this check.
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: what would be a search term that fails on what searched for text?

Comment: Why are you trimming it then? -edit- oh, nm - not finding any spaces? I'd say posted text is encoded, and you need to url decode the parm values.

Comment: make sure to use mysql_real_escape_string in your query http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: If I search for a part number like 420 99 4710 00 04 which is identical to the part number in the database then the result shows that is isnt in my database!

Answer (score 1):

`%` will only insert wildcards on the outside of the search text as a whole. You will need to write a more complex query if you want to handle multiple-word search strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
$searchTerms = explode(' ', $find);
$searchTermBits = array();
foreach ($searchTerms as $term) {
    $term = trim($term);
    if (!empty($term)) {
        $searchTermBits[] = "vendor LIKE '%$term%'";
    }
}
```

then in query just implode the $searchTermBits instead of $term